# File encoding Ascii-8bit to Utf-8

Tags: ruby, file, encoding, ascii-8bit

Meanwhile xml file seems encoded in utf-8 format on Windows Os (seen in NotePad++), output some content of this file read as ascii-8bit is badly returned into the output file.

```
xml = Ox.load_file(ENV["HOME"] + '/desktop/sample.xml', mode: :generic, with_xml: true )

outcsv=[]
string = xml.FOO.BAR.text
outcsv.push(string)
outcsv.push( "Default external: #{Encoding.default_external.inspect}" )
outcsv.push( "Default internal: #{Encoding.default_internal.inspect}" )
outcsv.push( "Locale charmap:   #{Encoding.locale_charmap.inspect}"   )
outcsv.push( "LANG environment variable: #{ENV['LANG'].inspect}" )
p outcsv.count

def exportCsv (arr) #{{{

  outcsvpath = ENV['HOME'].to_s+'/desktop/out.csv'
  f = File.new(outcsvpath, File::RDWR|File::CREAT, 0644)
  arr.each { |row|
    f.puts(row.to_s.force_encoding('cp1252').encode('utf-8'))  #iso-8859-1
  }
  f.close()

end #}}}
```

**The xml input:**

> Présent
>       dernière vérification
>       text at bottom

**The output text line and default encoding:**

```
> PrÃ©sent derniÃ¨re vÃ©rification 
> Default external: #<Encoding:UTF-8>
> Default internal: nil 
> Locale charmap:   "CP1252" LANG environment
> variable: "FR"
```

Comment: The xml input is a raw text string? That doesnt make sense.
And just be aware: If you have an xml with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>` it doesn't mean necessarily that it is UTF-8. It means only, that somebody wanted to have it as UTF-8.

Comment: No xml input a real xml file. And Ox parser with option with_xml: true take account about encoding.

Answer (score 0):

It works with this code:

```
require 'ox'

#Encoding.default_external = Encoding.find('utf-8')
#Encoding.default_internal = Encoding.find('utf-8')


# 1. Xml Generic Mode
xml = Ox.load_file(ENV["HOME"] + '/desktop/sample.xml', mode: :generic, with_xml: true )

outcsv=[]
string = xml.FOO.BAR.text
outcsv.push( string )
outcsv.push( "Default external: #{Encoding.default_external.inspect}" )
outcsv.push( "Default internal: #{Encoding.default_internal.inspect}" )
outcsv.push( "Locale charmap:   #{Encoding.locale_charmap.inspect}"   )
outcsv.push( "LANG environment variable: #{ENV['LANG'].inspect}"      )
p outcsv.count

def exportCsv (arr) #{{{

  outcsvpath = ENV['HOME'].to_s+'/desktop/out.csv'
  f = File.new(outcsvpath, File::RDWR|File::CREAT, 0644)
  arr.each { |row|
    f.puts(row.to_s) #.force_encoding('Windows-1252').encode('utf-8'))  #iso-8859-1
  }
  f.close()
end #}}}
```